# Does anyone have this book to share? [Julia, A Life in Mathematics. By Constance Reid]

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm not sure if it is a book or kind of an article, but it was published by the  Mathematical Association of America (MAA): [https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/julia-a-life-in-mathematics.](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/julia-a-life-in-mathematics)

If you have the file, could you please share to me? it is for academic purposes (libraries are closed)

I need it because it seems that it's the "official biography" of Julia Robinson. And I want to know as much as I can about her.

Comment: It can be checked out from archive.org: https://archive.org/details/julialifeinmathe0000reid

Comment: Great that it's amazing! but 1 hour is a very short time to read a whole book!

Comment: Constance Reid also wrote *Hilbert*, an utterly fascinating biography of Guess Who(???).

Comment: @RobertLewis David Hilbert I guess? But I need only their work on Julia Robinson.

Comment: @JoséMarín:  yes, David HIlbert.  Sorry I couldn't help with your specific request.  I thought some of your readers might be interested . . . ***Cheers!***

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you.